# Can we load child path of Foo Component from some differnet Compontent, using the current route information?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

What I need:

The application has a `side-nav` component, that has menu to load features and sub-menu to load sub features. sub features are child routes of features.

I tried using a some sample application (with similar functionality). I have tried following ways. Please help me with correct approach to do this? and why this is resulting in errors?

-- *app.component.html* --

```
<app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

-- *side-nav.component.html* --

```
<div class="side-nav">
    <p>side-nav works!</p>
    <div (click)="showFooChild()">Show Foo Child</div>
</div>
```

-- *side-nav.component.ts* --

```
  showFooChild(){

    //I have tried all the following ways 

    // this.router.navigate(["foo-child"])  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["/foo-child"])  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["./foo-child"])  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["../foo-child"])  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["foo-child"],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["/foo-child"],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})  //Error
    // this.router.navigate(["./foo-child"],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})  //Error
     this.router.navigate(["../foo-child"],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})  //Error

  }
```

-- *ERROR*--

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'foo-child'
```

-- *foo.component.html* --

```
<p>foo works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:"foo",
    component: FooComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path:"foo-child",
        component: FooChildComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You route config is set up so that `foo-child` is a child route of `foo` - so the full route URL is `/foo/foo-child`

Use `this.router.navigate(["foo/foo-child"])` to go there.

Do not use the `relativeTo:this.activatedRoute` option because if you were at another route, for example `/bar` then it would try to navigate to `/bar/foo/foo-child` which does not exist.  Since these component always exists you will always need to navigate to an absolute path, not a relative one.

Comment: I have just mentioned one feature `foo` , there could be multiple features each with its sub-features. I do not want it to be dynamic based on the current select feature. I do not want to go with static implimentation like `this.router.navigate(["foo/foo-child"])` as adding these way for multiple features may look ineffective way

Comment: Ah ok, is there any particular reason you need to do `router.navigate(...)` instead of just having an `<a>` tag in the HTML?  How many top-level routes will there be that have this same `foo-child` sub-route?  Will there be any top-level routes that **will not** have the `foo-child` sub-route?

Comment: I have refactored by code to perform navigations from the Feature. But I am still wondering why cant we perform the routing for the Feature from the SideNav after all its the same `Router` instance used to perform `router.navigate(...)`.